# AegisImplicitMail asp.net html body email

Tags: html, asp.net, email

I am trying to send mail in asp.net whit AegisImplicitMail. My code is:

```
    string OggettoEmailIta = "Oggetto email";

    string TestoEmailIta = "<p>aaa</p><br/><div>bbb</div>";

    var mailMessage = new MimeMailMessage();

    mailMessage.Subject = OggettoEmailIta;

    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

    mailMessage.Body = TestoEmailIta;
    mailMessage.Sender = new MimeMailAddress("XXX", "XXX");
    mailMessage.From = new MimeMailAddress("XXX", "XXX");
    mailMessage.To.Add(new MimeMailAddress("XXX", "XXX"));
    mailMessage.To.Add(new MimeMailAddress("XXX", "XXX"));

    var emailer = new SmtpSocketClient();
    emailer.Host = "smtp.XXX.XX";
    emailer.Port = 465;
    emailer.SslType = SslMode.Ssl;
    emailer.User = "XXX";
    emailer.Password = "XXX";
    emailer.AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationType.Base64;

    emailer.MailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

    emailer.MailMessage = mailMessage;

    emailer.SendMailAsync();
```

The mail is sent correctly but **it is not in HTML format**.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

you might try string literals "@" for your html message, so all chars are kept

```
string TestoEmailIta = @"<p>aaa</p><br/><div>bbb</div>";
```

Comment: Didn't help to me